# Washer drain pan installation

Tags: plumbing, drain, washer

I am trying to install the drain pan for the washer. I found the pipe to fit in the drain pipe underneath the tile.(when I put 3/4 inch pipe inside the pipe underneath the tile, it goes few inches down and stops) 
I pour the water to see the water goes away. I have a question. All water I pour supposed to go away in the pipe underneath the tile? Or some amount of water will still stay in the pipe because the pipe underneath the tile is connected to another pipe as ‘U’ shape or something?
I spent few days to figure out how to connect the washer pan drain and the pipe underneath the tile. Now I am stuck in another issue because I don’t know the pipe underneath the tile can drain water or not. 
[image][image]

Comment: If you keep pouring water in the pipe and it drains away, then I think you can assume this goes to a drain. Is this the service drain for the clothes washer or to be used only in case the washer overflows?

Comment: Thank you Jim! This is for only in case the washer overflows.